# Only last <img> attribute gets outputted while the others don't

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to output a couple of images onto the screen. I am fetching them using  attribute.

The code which contains the image sources:

```
var animal = '<div class = "gallery"><img src = "https://i.pinimg.com/474x/17/16/bd/1716bd0cc651bd9be7852e02dfc3d56c.jpg" loading = "lazy" alt = "animal"></div>';
var food = '<div class = "gallery"><img src = "https://i.pinimg.com/originals/44/f6/5e/44f65ecf8cd629fcf84c419efb40e3ef.png" loading = "lazy" alt = "food"></div>';
var flower = '<div class = "gallery"><img src = "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/proxy/8sq7n7yfJ3TbY6-vaDEa9Ey-VyChfXdmLLo8Rf8VZUzz7e-ncgud_HjXgh589pTbA9fEJdFnGvhhavaC_Sh0Q6wF6lxKuNe4ZMUL5GYcvLmZmoRsqn2lQO5B97evBjezfzSIHg" loading = "lazy" alt = "flower"></div>';
```

I also tried without the `<div>`, but it doesn't work.

And here is the code where I am trying to output them:

```
document.getElementById("bottom").innerHTML = animal;
document.getElementById("bottom").innerHTML = food;
document.getElementById("bottom").innerHTML = flower;
```

I want an output like this:
[image: Three images]
But the output I get is only the last image (red flower).

How can I show all of the images?

Comment: Assignment is a replacement.  Appending would be `+=`

Comment: Could you please write a part of the code on what you mean? I tried (hopefully what you meant) and it still didn't work

Comment: Literally change your second and third assignment to be `+=` instead.  If that does not work, then please make an [mcve] of your issue.

Comment: It worked :D but now each image is below one another.

Comment: Sure, `<div>` elements by default are display: block

Comment: Okay I see what you mean, but with every display property I give it, they are still stacked one below another

Comment: at this point your current issue has diverged from your original issue.  If you have a secondary issue around css styling of the elements, that should be a new question.

Comment: Fair point, gonna try not to stray from the main question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that `innerHTML` overwrites the contents of an element, according to the documentation:

> The innerHTML property **sets** or returns the HTML content (inner HTML) of an element.

So your code changes the contents of your `<div>` every time you call `innerHTML`.
Replace `=` by `+=` and that's it!
Your code:

```js
var animal = '<div class = "gallery"><img src = "https://i.pinimg.com/474x/17/16/bd/1716bd0cc651bd9be7852e02dfc3d56c.jpg" loading = "lazy" alt = "animal"></div>';
var food = '<div class = "gallery"><img src = "https://i.pinimg.com/originals/44/f6/5e/44f65ecf8cd629fcf84c419efb40e3ef.png" loading = "lazy" alt = "food"></div>';
var flower = '<div class = "gallery"><img src = "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/proxy/8sq7n7yfJ3TbY6-vaDEa9Ey-VyChfXdmLLo8Rf8VZUzz7e-ncgud_HjXgh589pTbA9fEJdFnGvhhavaC_Sh0Q6wF6lxKuNe4ZMUL5GYcvLmZmoRsqn2lQO5B97evBjezfzSIHg" loading = "lazy" alt = "flower"></div>';
document.getElementById("bottom").innerHTML += animal;
document.getElementById("bottom").innerHTML += food;
document.getElementById("bottom").innerHTML += flower;
```

```html
<div id="bottom"></div>
```

Or:

```js
var animal = '<div class = "gallery"><img src = "https://i.pinimg.com/474x/17/16/bd/1716bd0cc651bd9be7852e02dfc3d56c.jpg" loading = "lazy" alt = "animal"></div>';
var food = '<div class = "gallery"><img src = "https://i.pinimg.com/originals/44/f6/5e/44f65ecf8cd629fcf84c419efb40e3ef.png" loading = "lazy" alt = "food"></div>';
var flower = '<div class = "gallery"><img src = "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/proxy/8sq7n7yfJ3TbY6-vaDEa9Ey-VyChfXdmLLo8Rf8VZUzz7e-ncgud_HjXgh589pTbA9fEJdFnGvhhavaC_Sh0Q6wF6lxKuNe4ZMUL5GYcvLmZmoRsqn2lQO5B97evBjezfzSIHg" loading = "lazy" alt = "flower"></div>';
document.getElementById("bottom").innerHTML = document.getElementById("bottom").innerHTML + animal;
document.getElementById("bottom").innerHTML = document.getElementById("bottom").innerHTML + food;
document.getElementById("bottom").innerHTML = document.getElementById("bottom").innerHTML + flower;
```

```html
<div id="bottom"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you :DD you and Taplar really helped!